# SSIS: Why won't my Text Delimiter work?

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, runtime-error, truncate

Originally I had wrote the following:

> Environment:
>   - **`SSIS 2012`, `Microsoft Visual Studio`**
>
> Files Involved: Destination Manager: `OLEDB` `SQL Server` Table
>
> Source Manager: **FLATFILE** - `CSV` File
>
> ```
>     FORMAT: Delimited
>     HeadRowDelimiter: {CR}{LF}
>     Column Delimiter: Comma {,}
>     Text qualifier: " (manually set)
>     Header rows to skip: 0
>     Column Width: 100
>     Column Type: DT_STR
> ```
>
> My File has the following columns:
>
> ```
> Year, Lg..., Div Finish, Playoffs, PF, PA...OSRS, DSRS
> ```
>
> I wish to only retrieve:
>
> ```
> Year, Lg..., Div Finish, Playoffs
> ```
>
> But instead of:
>
> ```
> |2015,'NFL',...,'2nd of 4',NULL,...,-4,0.3
> |2014,'NFL',...,'3rd of 4',NULL,...,0.6,-4.4
> ```
>
> The `SSIS` package would fail with a message similar to this:
>
> ```
> [NFL_Team_List [52]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Playoffs" returned status value 4 and status
> ```
>
> text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the
>   target code page.".
>
> However, looking at the data that did go through a couple of times, I
>   notice the following:
>
> ```
> |2015,'NFL',...,'2nd of 4','339,345,-6,Quinn,Jones,Ryan...'
> |2014,'NFL',...,'3rd of 4','299,422,-123,Reeves Phillips,Brooking...'
> ```

So the problem was on my delimiters are not acting like delimiters! Even though I set the Text Qualifier setting, it seems that `SSIS` is unable to actually enforce this rule in the dynamic `FOREACHLOOP`, leading to the issue.

**QUESTIONS:**

- Why is this the case?
- How can I get the Text Qualifier to work as designed?

Comment: It sounds like you are not mapping all the colums. I would map all the columns (including PF, PA...OSRS, DSRS) and discard them on the OLE DB mapping.

Comment: @verceli That is how it was initially setup. However, that is not best practice and SSIS uses extra resources going through the files. Plus, SSIS clearly thinks it is not normal as it sends me warning when i do that. And I would think as someone determined to be great at what I do that I stick to the Standard as close as I can. :/

Comment: Could you provide your target table definition and two rows of data - one that has made it in and one that fails? There are too many ellipses in your problem statement for us to make an informed guess as to what the issue is.

Comment: @billinkc revampled the question to appropriately fit SO. I suppose writing it at 3 in the morning was a bad idea. xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set your text qualifier to " but it is actually '

Comment: hmm, it does not seem to do anything, though. :/

Comment: Does "it does not seem to do anything" really mean you are getting the same error?

Comment: revamped the question. Should be more clear what the problem is. Also renamed question.

Comment: When I look at your latest edit there are no text qualifiers anywhere... so we seem to have a moving target

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, hence why I renamed the question. :/ What I thought was my problem was revealed was not. Should I just repost the question then for clarity?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I think I am going to edit this post so his answer is correct and repost the new (revealed) problem I am dealing with. He did answer the initial question...though it does not solve the main issue