# How can I ensure SSIS recognizes the new position of the {CL}{RF} when I limit the number of columns from a CSV Source?

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, runtime-error, delimiter

This turned into a two part problem when it was revealed the issue was not with [Text Delimiters - Previous Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200398/ssis-why-wont-my-text-delimiter-work).

My Environment is SSIS 2012 as powered by Visual Studio.

**Source:** CSV File **Delimiters Set:** None. However, CSV will insert {"} in columns that contain a column delimiter.

```
Columns: Year,Lg,Tm,W,L,T,Div Finish,Playoffs,PF,PA,PD,Coaches,AV,Passer,Rusher,Receiver,Pts,Yds,Pts,Yds,T/G,Pts±,Yds±,out of,MoV,SoS,SRS,OSRS,DSRS
Columns kept in extraction: Year,Lg,Tm,W,L,T,Div Finish,Playoffs
Column Delimiter: Comma{,}
ColumnType: Delimited
DataType: string [DT_STR]
OutputColumnWidth: 100 (modified)
TextQualified: True
```

[image: Flow_Chart2]

**Flat File Connection Manager Properties also contain:**

```
Expressions - ConnectionString : @[User::File_Name]
```

My target table is purely a loading table to handle in `SSIS`.

[image: Flow_Chart]

**Target Table (by design, error never gets to this file)**

```
[schema].[table]
Team_ID      VARCHAR(100)
Durable_Key  VARCHAR(100)
Year         VARCHAR(100)
Lg           VARCHAR(100)
Tm           VARCHAR(100)
W            VARCHAR(100)
L            VARCHAR(100)
T            VARCHAR(100)
[Div Finish] VARCHAR(100)
Playoffs     VARCHAR(100)
```

Note that these files ended up being the only acceptable files that accurately defined NFL recognized relationships of teams over the years even preceding a team's days in the NFL as far back as 1921.

**This set of rows were acceptable in SSIS**

```
1929,NFL,Buffalo Bisons,1,7,1,10th of 12,,48,142,-94,Jolley,,,,,9,1,10,1,1,10,1,12,-10.4,0.4,-10,-4.8,-5.2
1927,NFL,Buffalo Bisons,0,5,0,12th of 12,,8,123,-115,Batterson,,,,,12,1,12,1,1,12,1,12,-23,0.5,-22.5,-6.8,-15.7
```

**And these rows are the ones that failed immediately**

```
1944,NFL,Brooklyn Tigers,0,10,0,5th of 5,,69,166,-97,KubaleCawthonBridges,,McGibbony,Manders,Masterson,10,9,5,5,9,8,8,11,-9.7,3.1,-6.6,-9.4,2.8
1943,NFL,Brooklyn Dodgers,2,8,0,4th of 5,,65,234,-169,Cawthon,,McAdams,Manders,Martin,8,8,7,8,6,8,8,10,-16.9,2.1,-14.8,-12.7,-2.1
[Flat File Source [14]] Error: An error occurred while processing file "[File_Path]" on data row 2.
```

- All other settings were left to their default settings except as was necessary for using the `FOREACHLOOP`.
- The CodePage setting was never altered (1252)
- The only expression used in the `FOREACHLOOP` `Collection`s was `Name`, so it should not have an impact on the data.

**This is the full Error message:**

```
[NFL_Team_List [52]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Playoffs" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
[NFL_Team_List [52]] Error: The "NFL_Team_List.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[Playoffs]" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "NFL_Team_List.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[Playoffs]" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
[NFL_Team_List [52]] Error: An error occurred while processing file "[DESTINATION_PATH]/[FILE_NAME].csv" on data row 2.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on NFL_Team_List returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

While I thought the issue was compatibility related and also with the setting for Text Delimiters, this does not seem to be the case. SSIS is insisting on reading to the end of the {CL}{RF} position, and I cannot seem to get it to recognize a different column is the end of the row.

The result is the last column in the table absorbs the extra strings and of course overflows the column limits.

**- So how can I ensure `SSIS` recognizes the new position of the `{CL}{RF}` without absorbing the rest of the data in the column?**

Comment: The says that data in Playoffs column on row 2 was either truncated or contained characters that were not present in the code page.  An example of the later would be unicode character exists in non-unicode defined field.  Check all of the DataTypes and ensure the length and whether it is unicde (nchar) or non-unicode (char) is correct.  Make sure you have the Encoding set right on the flat file connection.  What is the for each loop for?

Comment: Also  don't try to limit or change the columns from the flat file connection!  That connection simply tells SSIS what the format is and what to expect changing that means SSIS interprets file differently than it should.  Post a couple images of your package flow because I am definitely not following what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Matt Sigh, that was my original solution to the entire thing. I do not alter anything, the target table is designed EXACTLY as the data coming, unless I can parse it as a string (to avoid errors). I have posted an update with the flow statement.

Comment: I see the header row as CRLF, but is the row delimiter set to CRLF too? Check in the columns section of flat file connection.  Then I know you mention the final table is exactly as it is coming in but are all of the data types the same? string [DT_STR] Width 100?  Check Advanced on section on flat file connection, columns in your transformation and columns in your destination object

Comment: Also I am still a little confused what you are doing with the foreach loop and this file because you are making it sound like your csv is populating the foreach loop and then doing some other data operation. but your showing that you are using the csv inside your data flow so nothing to do with the foreach loop.....?

Comment: also open the csv in something like notepad++ and look at the line endings and make sure they are consistent as CRLF I have one datasource that messes it up so I have had to script task and fix the file before importing.

Comment: @Matt I have 86 different FACT csv files that contains the NFL recognizes teams (and importantly,which teams were related). For example, there are Two different Indians teams that existed in the NFL. I need to recheck,but thr row should be CLRF...which is frustrating since I need that playoffs column to be the ending of the row. All I am doing here is extracting the data.

Comment: Why do you need playoffs to be end of the row?  Even if you don't want the rest of the data you still need to setup all  the columns in the flat file connection and just ignore them in your data transformation/function

Comment: Is that best practice? From SQL queries, we are taught not to waste resources bringing data we do not need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116716/discussion-between-clifton-h-and-matt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad we figured out where our confusion was.  Flat File Connections are simply the definition of the data source.  So it is not the place to limit what columns you want to use and which you do not.  In your Source component in the data flow task you can limit columns but deleting them from the output in the advanced editor.  you can also just ignore the columns you do not want.